# After Excel Open Format is changing in C#

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am opening an excel file using an already saved excel template. But the problem is after open the excel format is completely changed. I can't figure out where the problem is.

Here is my code for Excel Open -

```
private void OpenExcel(string fileName)
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/temp/"), fileName);
        var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            Excel.Workbooks books = excelApp.Workbooks;
            Excel.Workbook sheet = books.Open(fullPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 0, true, 1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlExtractData);
            System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);

        }
    }
```

My original format looks like this-
[image: Original Excel]

But the opened excel looks like this
[image]

Comment: In the second image, Excel indicates that the file has been repaired. Apparently the file is corrupted in some way or is in some non-standard format. When you open it by specifying `xlExtractData` you're telling it to try to open the file and show you what it can. Try checking the format when you save the original file.

Comment: @ScottHannen When I save the file, the file is in proper format. Even if I download the file the format is proper. It is only when I open the file in excel the format changes.